# Mix CSOM and JSOM? Any disadvantages?

Tags: office-365, csom, jsom, oauth

I need to write an Office365-App. I want to use a provider-hosted MVC-Application for this.

As I want to use some kind of "API" on some pages, that returns a JSON that then is used inside JS to display data: Can I just mix CSOM and JSOM?

Has this any effect on the (OAuth)-Authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I tested, there's definitely no problem in mixing JavaScript Object Model and C# client Object Model. Your provider-hosted app is like a SharePoint-hosted app (JavaScript OM) + a third-party server that can use C# client OM with oAuth authentication. Both worlds won't interfere.

However, as often, there's a little maintenance problem: you definitely need to document/explain why you have to maintain code in two locations and two languages...